# log request/response of .net SOAP web service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asmx, soap-extension

I'm consuming a third party .NET SOAP WebService (.asmx). I want to log request and response. I have seen some solutions using [SoapExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). But I like to integrate logging in my system, some like this:

```
public class MyWebService : ThirdPartyWebService
{
    public string Request { ... }
    public string Response {... }
}
```

Could i do this? Is there another solution?

UPDATE: I like avoid to serialize request and response object. But I´m doing this now.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer on this?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/880445/Logging-SOAP-web-service-envelop-request-and-reply

Answer (score 2):

you can use Fiddler: fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

or Web development helper: projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper

Here is soap extension sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38986/Trace-SOAP-Request-Response-XML-with-TraceExtensio.aspx

Comment: thx for answer. I know fiddler but i need for auditing not for debugging. codeproject is similar to msdn article.